# WCF vs Web API preference

Tags: wcf, rest, asp.net-web-api, wcf-web-api

I currently have a WCF service that the website uses to display data. I also use the same service to run a computation that takes about 8-9 hours and it saves the data it computed into the database during the time (the process/server stays alive). The WCF is only used by the website.

Should I switch to ASP.NET Web API? Can Web API run computation for like 8-9 hours and stay alive like the WCF? Basically I can call the web address and it initiates the computation and I also use different web address to get the data for the clients.

Should I even consider Web API?

Comment: My 2 cents - if it's not broke, don't mess with it.  Moving from WCF to Web API would be a complete rewrite.

Comment: They are both at the end of the day just APIs. There is nothing that stops either from being used the way you are suggesting. That said, most people run these in IIS, which in its default configuration (or any configuration before IIS 8) is completely unsuited for long running processes.

Comment: Does your WCF web service keep the connection open for 9 hours?

Comment: Only during the computation run. It is alive and running the calculation. The service/process stays alive.